# dnsmasq не работает маршрутизация

Tags: ubuntu, dns

В общем решил я добавить свой домен, который должен вести на локальную машину. Для этого

Посмотрел что в системе уже установлен **dnsmasq-base** и слушает 53-й порт (`sudo netstat -lnpt`)

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1311/teamviewerd
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11205/dnsmasq   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      856/cupsd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1587/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      7378/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      856/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1587/master
```

Нашел его конфиг файл (`locate dnsmasq.conf` -> `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/dnsmasq.conf`)

Добавил в его начало `address=/loc/127.0.0.1`

Сохранил и перезапустил службу (`sudo service network-manager restart`
)

Проверил работает ли маршрутизация (`ping -a test.loc`)

> ping: unknown host test.loc

Файл конфигурации у меня выглядит так

```
address=/loc/127.0.0.1

<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
        <policy user="root">
                <allow own="uk.org.thekelleys.dnsmasq"/>
                <allow send_destination="uk.org.thekelleys.dnsmasq"/>
        </policy>
        <policy user="dnsmasq">
                <allow own="uk.org.thekelleys.dnsmasq"/>
                <allow send_destination="uk.org.thekelleys.dnsmasq"/>
        </policy>
        <policy context="default">
                <deny own="uk.org.thekelleys.dnsmasq"/>
                <deny send_destination="uk.org.thekelleys.dnsmasq"/>
        </policy>
</busconfig>
```

Идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. вы указали доменное имя `loc`:

   ```
   address=/loc/127.0.0.1
   ```

   а пытаетесь резолвить доменное имя `test.loc`

   вам его и надо было тогда указывать:

   ```
   address=/test.loc/127.0.0.1
   ```
2. тот файл, что вы нашли, не является конфигурационным файлом программы *dnsmasq*. это конфигурационный файл программы *dbus*. своей правкой вы его явно «поломали».

   насколько понимаю, дополнительную конфигурацию программы *dnsmasq*, вызываемой программой *network-manager*, следует указывать [в файлах в каталоге `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dnsmasq_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#NetworkManager)

Comment: попробовал добавить строку в `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/cache`, не помогло, видимо конфиг не подтягивается, либо что-то нужно еще. Доставил отдельно чистый dnsmasq и появился еще один конфиг `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` которы решил проблемму

Comment: @Ninazu `cache` — это просто пример имени файла. не знаю, как у вас в системе сконфигурирована *dnsmasq* (именно тот экземпляр, что запускается программой *network-manager*), потому предлагаю просто попробовать добаить к имени файла суффикс `.conf`.

Comment: изначально пробовал с суффиксом, всё равно не помогло. Кстати резолвятся все имена заканчивающиеся на **.loc** , и нет необходимости их перечислять. Собственно для этого я и настраивал dnsmasq, перечислить и в hosts можно было.

Comment: Сейчас кстати у меня в netstat два адреса прибиндило. `127.0.0.1` и `127.0.1.1` Возможно нужно было просто указать не тот IP и завелось бы. Будет время попробую разобраться в чём было дело